# Does Router automatically exclude default-router address from DHCP leasing?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, dhcp, cisco-commands

I am confused with what happens to the `default router` adddress when we are configuring `DHCP` in the router.

I have the network with 253 hosts, `192.168.1.0/24`, and I have configured `DHCP` in my network.

Now, while configuring DHCP, I have excluded the first four IP address of the network using `ip dhcp exclude-address` command, but I haven't excluded the address that I have used as a `default-router` address in DHCP configuration, which is the last address of the network, i.e. `192.168.1.254`.

Now, I am confused that, since I didn't excluded that last ip address and point it to a `default-router` will router try to lease that address ?

If not, is it automatically excluded ? or do I have to exclude it myself to avoid any conflict ?

**EDIT:** `default-router` is pointing to another router where hosts are connected, and where `ip helper-address` is configured.

I am using 1841 Router in Packet Tracer.

Comment: That depends on the router model. You should edit your question to include the router model.

Comment: hi, its 1841. and I am using Packet tracer. I have modified my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cisco ISR router like the 1841 excludes the router's address on the subnet for which DHCP is configured if the router is performing DHCP.

If you have two routers and an FHRP on the subnet, you need to be more careful.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the best practice ? Is it recommended to always exclude `default-router` address no matter what the model is ?

Comment: It won't hurt to exclude it. Whether or not you _need_ to depends on the router and software. If your network is heterogeneous, you may want to do that as a best practice since it could be problematic to remember which routers require it, and which don't.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. :)
Thanks heaps, now everything is clearer.